# cannot make comparison when taking the contents of character sequence into string variable C++

Tags: c++, char, sequences

First, I am learning C++, and need your help with an issue I have...
I have the following piece of code:

```
std::string var2;
std::string MSG1="1";
char charSeq[1024];

cout << charSeq << endl;
var2 = charSeq;
cout << var2 << endl;
```

The above does for me what I want, which is taking the contents of the character sequence named charSeq and put them in the string variable named var2
But when I want to do comparison or any operation on the string variable var2, I cannot, for example, if charSeq has the value of 1, and I assigned this value to var2, then I made comparison between MSG and var2, the result is always false, like var2 has no value or has a wrong value...

```
if (var2==MSG1)
{
     // the code here never gets executed, even when the values are the same in var2 and MSG...
}
else
{
     // the result is always false and this condition executed no matter what var2 and MSG values were...
}
```

Can you help me with some tips on this?

Comment: Hint: You're trying to use a chunk of memory that is full of garbage as a string.

Comment: I understand that the charSeq must have a null terminator for this to work?

Comment: I could just convert it to normal char then using for loop?

Comment: Is charSeq ever initialized? Can you post the exact code you are having problems with?

Comment: Yes. Simply doing `char charSeq[1024]` allocates 1024 bytes on the stack and doesn't set the values of that memory to anything, so it has whatever garbage in it that was there before. You have to put a string in the memory before using it to do things properly. If you only want one single character, then use `char`, not `char[]`. And why are you using character arrays instead of `std::string` anyway?

Comment: Did you assign a value to `charSeq`? It works if you initialize the char array ([working example](http://ideone.com/LWFNN)).

Comment: Yea, I'll just post the code, it is a receive function

Comment: Can you post a short, self-contained, correct (compilable) example? [link](http://sscce.org/). It will be easier for people to help you with your problem if we have a small, compilable program to look at. That way we don't have to make assumptions about how you're using the code snippets you provided.

Comment: Here is the code: [link](http://ideone.com/W91aJ)

Comment: @Bluescrod print the length of `var2` to see if there are invisible characters in it, if when printing it and `MSG1` they look the same. The length should be exactly one or it can't be equal to `"1"`

Comment: OK, I solved this, I found 2 extra characters not showing, so I used erase function and erased the last 2 characters from var2 and everything was OK after that... Thanks Seth and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comment from Seth above (thank you very much for the tip of the length), I managed to solve the issue:
I was having 2 invisible characters in charSeq, and those were copied to var2, this was causing the false result of the comparison, what I did is:

```
cout << "charseq length: " << strlen(charSeq) << endl;
cout << "var2 length: " << var2.length() << endl;

var2.erase(var2.length()-2,var2.length()); //here is what i did...

cout << "var2 new length: " << var2.length() << endl; // the result was the correct length of the visible characters, and the comparison condition was executed...
```

Thanks again for all of you...